# How to hide soft keyboard and keep input on focus

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, mobile, barcode-scanner

I have a page for a barcode scanner(honeywell ct50) running Android 4.4.4,
The soft keyboard pops up automatically as input textbox is on focus.
Is there any solution to hide it?
I have read suggestions, mostly making the input losing focus or being readonly,
but I need to keep the focus on the input to read the barcode.

I tried 
1. to execute event.preventDefault() in onfocus event, it doesn't work.
2. to get the barcode on document.keypress(), the solution in the post as below, but nothing got from my scanner.
[javascript - hide mobile default keyboard but keep input field active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979445/javascript-hide-mobile-default-keyboard-but-keep-input-field-active)

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: why are you referring  to javascript? Is it not a native application?

Comment: Have you found a solution, we've ran into the same problem in a Web App that uses barcode scanner on the same device and need to hide the keyboard while keeping focus on a text field

Answer (score 5):

Old topic but this is the solution which works at least for android 6 and 7:

```
yourInput = document.getElementById('yourInputElement');
yourInput.readOnly = true;
yourInput.focus();
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('yourInputElement').readOnly = false;}, 50);
```

You put your input in readOnly = true before the focus.
The keyboard will not appear.
And you put back the input in readOnly = false but not immediately.
So you can use your scanner without having the keyboard popping up.

Comment: this flickers the keyboard, but the best solution i can find

Comment: AFAICT this doesn't work on iOS. Or rather, the input shows as focused & the keyboard stays down, but the OS doesn't allow text to be entered into the focused text box (presumably it has some logic saying if the keyboard isn't active then nobody can enter text). Sadly even if I then tap the text box manually, the keyboard doesn't show and I still can't enter text. I have to tap somewhere else to blur it first, and *then* tap it in order for it to work again.

Comment: it works well on Android 10 of Honeywell EDA51 PDA, thx

Comment: Tested on UROVO DT-50 Android 12 device and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

For me what worked at some point was setting the ion-input type="text" to readonly, but now it is not working when setting that property. Maybe give it a try.